# How to retarget animation from Generic to Humanoid?

Tags: unity, animation

I am in a constant struggle to convert a character that is indeed a humanoid character but its rig has been assigned as a generic rig. I want it to be humanoid so I can easily retarget its animation and apply them to another character of my own.
The problem that I am facing is that the animations when I run from the Animation tab of Unity Editor Works just fine but when I try to play them from the Script. The animations doesn’t play at all.
I don’t know what could be the problem. I need help in this regard. I have explored google all around and I am in a need of serious help. If someone can I’ll be really very grateful.
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just change the character's animation setting in the Inspector from Generic to Humanoid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your animations in an animator and add that animator to the character. The animator have parameter property so that you can control which animation to show. Further explanation are are given on their website.